# Ignore Time-out errors in a cruisecontrol task

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a task running in cruisecontrol which is functioning correctly. Even though it works fine, cruisecontrol gives me a time-out error for that task !!!
When I verify the results of that task, I can see that the task has executed just fine.
I need to ignore that time-out error so that cruisecontrol gives me a green color on that task. Any solution for this?
I'm using cruisecontrol.net 1.6 latest build.

My Task looks like this:

```
<exec> 
    <executable>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</executable>
    <buildArgs> /c curl.exe "FileToBeUploaded" "RepositoryURL" </buildArgs> 
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>100</buildTimeoutSeconds> 
    <successExitCodes>1,0</successExitCodes> 
</exec>
```

Thanks.

Comment: CruiseControl.Net has no way of knowing that the task has finished if the process has not exited correctly - you have to fix this problem, ignoring it won't work.

Comment: timeout must be caused by some error while executing the task. Can you post your config files

Comment: my executable task goes like this.

    <exec>
 <executable>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</executable>
 <buildArgs>
  /c curl.exe "FileToBeUploaded" "RepositoryURL"
 </buildArgs>
 <buildTimeoutSeconds>100</buildTimeoutSeconds>
 <successExitCodes>1,0</successExitCodes>
    </exec>

The executable task does a file upload to a repository URL.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will just need to increase your time out value under the xml tag buildTimeoutSeconds. Try executing the curl from regular command line in the CruiseControl server and see how long it takes to get a rough execution time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, one can specify a <buildTimeoutSeconds> value of 0 to disable process timeouts.

http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task